# update matplotlib path interactively on figure and extract actual data for recalculation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, interactive

I have a plot where I want to interactively adjust the position of a patch and use the interactive update to be used in recalculating a variable.

I have plotted and image and added a closed contour (represented using PathPatch)

Here is an example image. [example image with contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQxf9.png) where information is calculated from the pixels enclosed by the contour. The pixel mask needs to be updated so that plots on right can also be updated.

Currently I plot everything and then use an event to move the contour, I tried using transforms and this worked to move the contour but when I tried using the transform to update the binary mask needed to recalculate the plots on the right side, the transformation it returns is incorrect. On top of this the transforms caused the contour to move when zooming in and out from the interactive window.

I need to figure out how to shift the contour and re-plot it and then extract the shift and apply to extracting a new mask of enclosed points to update the calculation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.path as mplpath
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.widgets import Button, Slider

# GENERATE SOME DATA TO PLOT
# event functions
def press(event):
    print('press', event.key)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if (event.key == 'left'):
        shift[0] -= 1.0
    elif (event.key == 'right'):
        shift[0] += 1.0
    elif (event.key == 'up'):
        shift[1] += 1
    elif (event.key == "down"):
        shift[1] -= 1.0

    # this is where I don't know how to properly transform and update[!       

    fig.canvas.draw()

class Recalculate(object):

    def update(self, event):
        x_update = [x_ for x_ in x_pts]
        y_update = [y_ for y_ in y_pts]
        verts_test = np.column_stack((x_update, y_update))
        new_contour = mplpath.Path(verts_test, closed=True)
        # create mask
        new_grid = getMask(im_vol_resize, new_contour)
        # calculate the flow
        q_sum = []
        for i in range(N): #assume size doesn't change
            q_mask_sum = np.sum(test_q[:,:,i]*new_grid.astype(image_dtype))
            q_sum.append(q_mask_sum*np.prod(spacing[0:2])/(100.0*scale**2)) # cm^3

        print("total flow {0} cm^3/beat".format(np.trapz( q_sum, dx = np.mean(mean_diff)/1000)))
        q_sum_roll = np.roll(q_sum, -16)
        #q_interp = interpolate.CubicSpline(new_time, q_sum_roll, bc_type='periodic')
        q_interp = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(new_time, q_sum_roll, k=3, ext=0)
        q_test = q_interp(t_interp)

        #plotting update
        grid_handle.set_data(new_grid)
        #print(new_time)
        scat_data = np.stack((new_time, q_sum), axis=1)
        #ax2.relim()      # make sure all the data fits
        #ax2.autoscale()
        #print(scat_data.shape)
        scatter_handle.set_offsets(scat_data)
        interp_handle[-1].set_ydata(q_test)
        ax3.relim()      # make sure all the data fits
        ax3.autoscale()
        ax2.set_xlim(ax3.get_xlim())
        ax2.set_ylim(ax3.get_ylim())
        fig.canvas.draw()

def update_cine(val):
    ind = int(slider.val)
    s = [slice(ind, ind + 1) if i == 2 else slice(None)
             for i in range(3)]
    for sd in xyz_keys:
        im = cubes[sd][s].squeeze()
        cine_ax_dict[sd].set_data(im)
    ax6.set_title("time: {0}".format(new_time[ind]))
    ax2.scatter(new_time, q_sum, c='b', label='flowRate')
    ax2.scatter(new_time[ind], q_sum[ind], c='r', label='time={0}'.format(new_time[ind]))
    fig.canvas.draw()

#figures
gs = plt.GridSpec(6, 6, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 9))
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:,0:3])
#xl = ax.set_xlabel('easy come, easy go')
#ax.set_title('Press a key')
patch = patches.PathPatch(contour, facecolor=(1.0,165./255.0,0,0.25), lw=1 )#, alpha=0.5)
patch_handle = ax.add_patch(patch)

#plt.plot(x_pts, y_pts)
x_bounds = [round((bounds[0]-4)*scale), round((bounds[1]+4)*scale)]
y_bounds = [round((bounds[2]-4)*scale), round((bounds[3]+4)*scale)]
ax.set_xlim(x_bounds)
ax.set_ylim(y_bounds)
ax.imshow(im_vol_resize, interpolation='bilinear', cmap="gray",  alpha=1.0)

ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:3,0:3])
patch2 = patches.PathPatch(contour, facecolor='none', linewidth=0.8, edgecolor=(1.0,165./255.0,0,0.50))#, alpha=0.5)
ax5.imshow(im_vol_resize, interpolation='bilinear', cmap="gray",  alpha=1.0)
patch_handle2 = ax5.add_patch(patch2)
#new_contour = patch_.get_path()
ax5.set_xlim(x_bounds)
ax5.set_ylim(y_bounds)

# show ROI mask
grid_handle = ax.imshow(grid, interpolation='None', cmap="gray",  alpha=0.1)
#print(dir(grid_handle))
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:3, 4:])
scatter_handle = ax2.scatter(new_time, q_sum, c='b', label='flowRate')
ax2.scatter(new_time[0], q_sum[0], c='r', label='cine time')
#print(dir(scatter_handle))
#ax2.scatter(dict_time["y"], q_sum, label='flowRatey')
#ax2.scatter(dict_time["z"], q_sum, label='flowRatez')
#ax2.plot(dict_time["x"], q_sum)
#ax2.set_xlabel(r'$t$', fontsize=20)
ax2.set_title('terminal ICA Waveform', fontsize=20)
ax2.set_ylabel(r'Q, $Q(t)$ $cm^3/min$', fontsize=20)
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax2.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax2.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.9))

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:, 4:])
ax3.set_xlabel(r'time $t$ $milliseconds$', fontsize=20)
ax3.set_ylabel(r'Flowrate $cm^3/min$', fontsize=20)
ax3.set_xlim(ax2.get_xlim())
ax3.set_ylim(ax2.get_ylim())

interp_handle = ax3.plot(t_interp, q_test, c='b', linestyle='-', label='interp')
#print(dir(interp_handle[0]))
ax3.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.9))

cine_ax_dict = {}
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2,2:4])
ax6.set_title("time: {0}".format(new_time[0]))
cine_ax_dict["x"] = ax6.imshow(cubes['x'][:,:,0], interpolation='bilinear', cmap="viridis",  alpha=1.0)
patch6 = patches.PathPatch(contour, facecolor='none', linewidth=0.8, edgecolor=(1.0,165./255.0,0,0.50))
ax6.add_patch(patch6)
ax6.set_xlim(x_bounds)
ax6.set_ylim(y_bounds)

ax7 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:4,2:4])
cine_ax_dict["y"] = ax7.imshow(cubes['y'][:,:,0], interpolation='bilinear', cmap="viridis",  alpha=1.0)
patch7 = patches.PathPatch(contour, facecolor='none', linewidth=0.8, edgecolor=(1.0,165./255.0,0,0.50))
ax7.add_patch(patch7)
ax7.set_xlim(x_bounds)
ax7.set_ylim(y_bounds)

ax8 = fig.add_subplot(gs[4:,2:4])
cine_ax_dict["z"] = ax8.imshow(cubes['z'][:,:,0], interpolation='bilinear', cmap="viridis",  alpha=1.0)
patch8 = patches.PathPatch(contour, facecolor='none', linewidth=0.8, edgecolor=(1.0,165./255.0,0,0.50))
ax8.add_patch(patch8)
ax8.set_xlim(x_bounds)
ax8.set_ylim(y_bounds)

# define slider
axcolor = 'lightslategray'
ax_c = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.05, 0.60, 0.03], aspect="auto", facecolor=axcolor)

slider = Slider(ax_c, 'Axis %i index' % 2, 0, cubes["x"].shape[2] - 1,
                valinit=0, valfmt='%i')
```